# Expected top-level entity

Tags: llvm

How did you managed to pass through `expected top-level entity` error while executing `lli` in the `llvm` framework?

Comment: Just say steps you have done and error message shown

Comment: Please show the command and the error produced.

Comment: Actually, I did not need to execute lli command for my purpose. I still have to experiment more with llvm tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error usually means that you copy-pasted part of some IR code which doesn't count as a top level entity. In other words, it's not a function, not a type, not a global variable, etc. The same error can happen in C, just for comparison:

```
x = 8;
```

Is not valid contents for a C file, because the assignment statement isn't a valid top level entity. To make it valid you put it in a function:

```
void foo() {
  x = 8;   /* assuming x is global and visible here */
}
```

The same error happens in LLVM IR.

Answer (score 5):

**My Issue:** The .ll file format was "UTF-8 with BOM" instead of "UTF-8 without BOM".

**Fix:** With notepad++, in the encoding menu, select the "UTF-8 without BOM", then save.

**Quick setup:** (For llvm 3.4.0 .ll files on windows)

advanced text editor from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

llvm binaries from https://github.com/CRogers/LLVM-Windows-Binaries

hello.ll as "UTF-8 without BOM" (This code is in llvm 3.4.0 format):

```
@msg = internal constant [13 x i8] c"Hello World!\00"
declare i32 @puts(i8*)
define i32 @main() {
    call i32 @puts(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8]* @msg, i32 0, i32 0))
    ret i32 0
}
```

In command prompt:

```
lli hello.ll
```

**Quick setup:** (For llvm 3.8.0 .ll files on windows)

advanced text editor from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

clang binaries from: http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.8.0

hello.ll as "UTF-8 without BOM" (This code is in llvm 3.8.0 format):

```
@msg = internal constant [13 x i8] c"Hello World!\00"
declare i32 @puts(i8*)
define i32 @main() {
    call i32 @puts(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @msg, i32 0, i32 0))
    ret i32 0
}
```

In command prompt:

```
clang hello.ll -o hello.exe
hello.exe
```

Errors about char16_t, u16String, etc means clang needs: -fms-compatibility-version=19